Android recycler view removing item
I have a recycler view and i am looking to remove a item from it but after removing my app is crashing. I am using firebase to store data and i also onDeleteClickListener but i didn't work.
every time I delete a item it deleted from the cart but the app also crashes.
giving me this error:
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.hungryhopper, PID: 8373
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0

I have made sure that my list has been initalized and used a log to ensure that both position and the list have values in them. I highlighted the problematic code:
My Adapter: 
    class CartAdapter(
    private val cartItems: MutableList<String>,
    private val cartItemsPrice: MutableList<String>,
    private val cartDescriptions: MutableList<String>,
    private val cartImages: MutableList<String>,
    private val cartQuantity: MutableList<Int>,
    private val cartIngredients: MutableList<String>,
    private val context: Context,
    private val onDeleteClickListener: (position: Int) -> Unit
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder>() {
    private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    init {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val userId = auth.currentUser?.uid ?: ""
        val cartItemNumber = cartItems.size
        itemQuantities = IntArray(cartItemNumber) { 1 }
        cartItemsReference =database.reference.child(USER_NODE).child(userId).child(CARTITEM_NODE)
    }
    companion object {
        private var itemQuantities = intArrayOf()
        private lateinit var cartItemsReference: DatabaseReference
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartViewHolder {
        return CartViewHolder(
            CartItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cartItems.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }
    inner class CartViewHolder(private val binding: CartItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(position: Int) {
            binding.apply {
                cartFoodName.text = cartItems[position]
                cartItemPrice.text = cartItemsPrice[position]
                quantity.text = itemQuantities[position].toString()
                val uriString = cartImages[position]
                val uri = Uri.parse(uriString.toString())
                Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(cartImage)
                minusButton.setOnClickListener {
                    decreaseQuantity(position)
                }
                plusButton.setOnClickListener {
                    increaseQuantity(position)
                }
                deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                    deleteItem(position)
                }
            }
        }
        private fun decreaseQuantity(position: Int) {
            if (itemQuantities[position] > 1) {
                itemQuantities[position]--
                cartQuantity[position] = itemQuantities[position]
                binding.quantity.text = itemQuantities[position].toString()
            }
        }
        private fun increaseQuantity(position: Int) {
            if (itemQuantities[position] < 10) {
                itemQuantities[position]++
                cartQuantity[position] = itemQuantities[position]
                binding.quantity.text = itemQuantities[position].toString()
            }
        }
        private fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
            val positionRetrieve = position
            getUniqueAtPosition(positionRetrieve) { uniqueKey ->
                if (uniqueKey != null) {
// The following fails with an IndexOutOfBoundsException: //
                    removeItem(position, uniqueKey)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun removeItem(position: Int, uniqueKey: String) {
        cartItemsReference.child(uniqueKey).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener {
            cartItems.removeAt(position)
            cartImages.removeAt(position)
            cartDescriptions.removeAt(position)
            cartQuantity.removeAt(position)
            cartItemsPrice.removeAt(position)
            cartIngredients.removeAt(position)
            itemQuantities = itemQuantities.filterIndexed { index, i -> index != position  }.toIntArray()
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, cartItems.size)
            Toast.makeText(context, " Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    private fun getUniqueAtPosition(i: Int, onComplete: (String?) -> Unit) {
        cartItemsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var uniqueKey: String? = null
                snapshot.children.forEachIndexed { index, dataSnapshot ->
                    if (index == i) {
                        uniqueKey = dataSnapshot.key
                        return@forEachIndexed
                    }
                }
                onComplete(uniqueKey)
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        })
    }

    fun getUpdatedItemQuantities(): MutableList<Int> {
        val itemQuantity = mutableListOf<Int>()
        itemQuantity.addAll(cartQuantity)
        return itemQuantity
    }
}

How can i delete something from it so that my app didnot crash. I can edit the quantity but can not delete the item.

Where does the exception occur?

when i am deleting a item from my cart in my app. I can decrease and increase the amount of item but on deleting the app is crashing

Ok, but which line is it in your code?

from line 107 deleteItem function to removeItem function there should be an error because of that the app is crashing but i cant find it.

I tried to highlight the relevant line in the code you provided. Is this correct?

Sorry, I actually didn't see that you also provided the removeItem function. Please [edit] your question to move the highlighter I just added to the specific line in that function.

Update below line in code:
notifyItemRangeChanged(0, cartItems.size)


It didn't work.
